# Remove dependency on netty-handler using WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, netty

I have a `spring-boot`(3.1.3) application that is using `Webclient` for web requests, by default this is using `Netty` as the embedded web server, there is a vulnerability present in `netty-handler` that I'd like to remove.

There is a version of `netty-handler`(5.0.0.Alpah1) that has no flagged vulnerability, I have migrated to `netty-handler`(5.0.0.Alpah1), and it has broken the application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/logging/ByteBufFormat
```

It looks like `Netty 5` is not compatible with `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` I have tried overriding other `Netty` dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty`, without success.

Reading the `spring-boot` docs, it's possible to change the embedded web server.

Out of the 3 other [options](https://hantsy.github.io/spring-reactive-sample/start/boot-first.html): `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, `spring-boot-starter-jetty`, or `spring-boot-starter-undertow` only `tomcat` has no flagged vulnerability.

After migrating to `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I observed, `mvn clean install` hangs on tests, also, when a call is made to another application, using `Webclient` there is an error thrown:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed
```

Reading the docs, it appears that even though we can change the embedded web server, `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` is required to use the `WebClient` class.

"[spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty is required to use the `WebClient` class, so you may need to keep a dependency on Netty even when you need to include a different HTTP server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.use-another)."

Anyway to remove the `netty-handler` vulnerability while still using `WebClient` ?

Comment: with tomcat you can exclude as you did and and netty-handler(5.0.0.Alpah1) maybe it'll work.